# How can i evaluate my regression model which has only one test and one predicted value?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, mean-square-error

So, I have used regression model with multiple training values and i am predicting only one value i.e. test set and predicted has only one value.
Now, i want to assess the model. How can i find the error score? please help.

I cannot use r squared as it has only one value. So, what do i do??

This is just the values that i have, not the full code

```py
y_test = [2615423.235]
y_pred = [2354948.662]
```

I have used r squared and it gives 0.0

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `error-handling` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

You can not evaluate your model with just one test data.
You can predict value but, it is not an evaluation step.

You told that you trained your model with multiple values. I think it means `n` number of data. Usually, We separate data as a training set and a testing set.

And you mentioned `error score`. I think you are saying about `cost`. It's calculated by training. But, You are saying about prediction and testing.

For the evaluation, an accuracy is more important point.